# Handling various errors in database connection - some not working?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I'm writing a script (mostly for learning purposes) for logging into a database, using two different mySQL DB's. Everything works, except some of the error catching. I have the following situations (the **bold ones** aren't working):

1. Blank username AND password
2. Blank username
3. Blank password
4. **Both username AND password contain data, but the *username* is wrong.**
5. **Both username AND password contain data, but the *password* is wrong.**
6. Both username AND password contain data, and are correct.

**Questions**: Am I going about this efficiently, and why are (4) and (5) returning blank.

```
<?php

    $loginstatus;
    if(!$_POST["username"] && !$_POST["password"]){ //FROM HERE
        $loginstatus = "You must enter a username & password!";
    }elseif(!$_POST["username"]){
        $loginstatus = "You must enter a username!";
    }elseif(!$_POST["password"]){
        $loginstatus = "You must enter a password!";//TO HERE WORKS
    }elseif($_POST["username"] && $_POST["password"]){ 
        require_once('config.php'); //contains db info
        $db1 = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $db2 = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser2, $dbpass2, true);

        if ($db1 && $db2) {                             //both connections must have worked at the same time
            mysql_select_db("nitrousc_tclydb", $db1);   //connect using $db1 link
            $userid = $_POST["username"];               //assign $userid to POST username
            $userid =  mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$userid'", $db1)or die("Invalid Password!"); //THIS RETUNRS BLANK!
            $userid = mysql_fetch_array($userid);       //reuse $userid again, assigning the returned array.

            $userid = $userid['id'];                    //reuse $userid again - at this point we lose the returned array.

            mysql_select_db("nitrousc_tclyprv", $db2);  //switch databases, using $db2

            $password =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$userid'", $db2) or die("Invalid Password!"); //THIS RETUNRS BLANK!
            $password = mysql_fetch_array($password);   //resuse $password
            $password = $password['hashed_password'];   //resuse, store final hashed in $password




            if (crypt($_POST["password"], $password) == $password){ //check the returned POST password against the hash
                $loginstatus = "Login for".$_POST['username']."succesful!"; //THIS WORKS
                };

        }

        }

    echo $loginstatus;











    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query` will **always** return true, it will only return false when the query is wrong.

What you need to check is:

```
$userid =  mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$userid'", $db1)or die("query error"); //THIS RETUNRS BLANK!
if(mysql_num_rows($userid) == 0){ //if no rows returned
     die("user id is wrong");
}
```

**ALSO** stop reusing the same variable for everything, that could lead to confusion and errors.